# Can't figure out why if condition is falsely triggered despite correct values printed before and after

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I can't figure out why my if condition is falsely triggering else despite the values used should trigger if condition.

> Example: previousduration: 297 thisduration: 66

It still goes into else showing "smaller" despite previousduration being larger (and same values are ouput before and after the if condition.

```
for (let n = 1; n <= totalslidesnr; ++ n){
  document.getElementById("durationrange"+n).addEventListener("input", function () {

    var prev = n-1;
var previousduration = document.getElementById("durationrange"+prev);
var thisduration = document.getElementById("durationrange"+n);

if (previousduration.value > thisduration.value) {
  console.log("larger");
  console.log("previousduration",previousduration.value);
  console.log("thisduration",thisduration.value);
}
else {
  console.log("smaller");
  console.log("previousduration",previousduration.value);
  console.log("thisduration",thisduration.value);
}
```

}
}

UPDATE FYI I'm using range input for durationrange

```
for (var n = 1; n <= totalslidesnr; ++ n){
$('<div class="line' + n + '" style="display:none;">' 
+ '<span style="width:60px; display:inline-block" >' 
+ 'Slide ' + n + '</span>' 
+ '<input type="text" id="durationtimestamp' + n + '" class=durationtimestamp' + n 
+ '" value="00:00" required="required" style="width:52px;"/> <input type="range" id="durationrange' 
+ n + '" class=durationslider' 
+ n + '" min="0" max="480" value="0" style="width:200px;vertical-align:middle"/>
</div>').appendTo(slidesdurationsDiv);
}
```

I checked type of variable

```
if(isNaN(previousduration.value)){
    document.write(previousduration.value + " is not a number");
    }
else{
    console.log(previousduration.value + " is a number");
 }
```

Outputs "is a number", same for the other variable.

But checking via typeof

```
if(typeof previousduration.value == 'number'){
     console.log(previousduration.value + " is a number");
    }else{
     console.log(previousduration.value + " is not a number");
    }
```

It returns "is not a number" :)

Comment: I suspect they are being compared as strings, not numbers.

Comment: On an unrelated note: Please write your variable names either in camel case, e.g. previousDuration, or use underscores to separate words, e.g. previous_duration --- This will make your variable names much easier to read.

Comment: @mykaf I've updated my thread with more info, I'm using range for input and checked the variable which seems to return being a number. Any other better way to check whether its a string? I just checked again via "typeof" which returned as not being a number, maybe I checked it wrong with isNaN.

Comment: Perhaps try `Number(previousduration.value)`, etc

Comment: Thanks @mykaf `Number()` works too, like `parseFloat` suggested previously by @andrea Roveroni. Is there any benefit of one over the other?

Comment: @Markus It seems there's not too much difference, from the docs in my answer: Syntax-wise, parseFloat() parses a subset of the syntax that the Number() function accepts. Namely, parseFloat() does not support non-decimal literals with 0x, 0b, or 0o prefixes but supports everything else. However, parseFloat() is more lenient than Number() because it ignores trailing invalid characters, which would cause Number() to return NaN. I think in 99% of cases you can use both, but do not use the keyword new when using Number, otherwise it will instantiate a Number object, not a primitive number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` property has type string, not number. As you can see here (you can try it yourself on your browser's console):

```
> "297" > "66"
false
> 297 > 66
true
```

You're comparing strings and not numbers.

You should convert those strings into numbers, maybe like this:

```
> parseFloat("297") > parseFloat("66")
true
```

Here you can find the documentation for [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat?retiredLocale=it)